# Spark Scala DataFrame and DataSet achieving desired out

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, dataset

I have a dataframe as below

```
scala> df.show
+----+------+
|SLNO|Values|
+----+------+
|   A|     y|
|   A|     t|
|   A|     e|
|   B|     f|
|   C|     g|
|   B|     h|
|   C|     k|
|   C|     u|
|   B|     p|
+----+------+
```

Expected Out would be :

```
SLNO Values
A    y,t,e
B    f,h,p
C    g,k,u
```

How can I achieve this via both DataFrame and DataSet model of Spark Scala ?.

I tried something like below in Dataset but got struck after this

```
    scala> ds.filter(line=> line.split("\t")(0).size <=1 ).map(line => Map(line.split("\t")(0) -> line.split("\t")(1)))
res86:org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = [value: map<string,string>]
```

// Don't know how to groupByKey further

Answer (score 0):

```scala
df.createOrReplaceTempView("df")
spark.sql("select SLNO, array_join(collect_list(Values), ',') as Values from df group by SLNO")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. your solution worked via Spark SQL. If you are familiar with Dataset Could you provide the solution for the same via Dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Check below code.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+----+------+
|slno|values|
+----+------+
|A   |y     |
|A   |t     |
|A   |e     |
|B   |f     |
|C   |g     |
|B   |h     |
|C   |k     |
|C   |u     |
|B   |p     |
+----+------+


scala> df
.groupBy("slno")
.agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list($"values")).as("values"))
.orderBy($"slno".asc)
.show(false)

+----+------+
|slno|values|
+----+------+
|A   |y,t,e |
|B   |f,h,p |
|C   |g,k,u |
+----+------+
```

```
scala> case class Example(slno: String,values:String)
defined class Example
```

```
scala> val ds = Seq(Example("A","y"),Example("A","t"),Example("A","e"),Example("B","f"),Example("C","g"),Example("B","h"),Example("C","k"),Example("C","u"),Example("B","p")).toDS
```

```
scala> ds
.groupBy("slno")
.agg(concat_ws(",",collect_list($"values")).as("values"))
.orderBy($"slno".asc)
.show(false)
+----+------+
|slno|values|
+----+------+
|A   |y,t,e |
|B   |f,h,p |
|C   |g,k,u |
+----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution resolved the issue via Dataframe. If you are familiar with Dataset could you please provide the solution for the same via Dataset.

Comment: added code, check now.